# What is the bit order of the quantization table information byte in a JPEG header?

Tags: parsing, visual-c++, byte, jpeg

I'm making a function to parse information from a jpeg header.
I can successfully locate the quantization table information byte (third byte after the  `0xFF 0xDB` marker). I know that half of the byte denotes the precision level of the table, while the other half is the identification number for that quantization table.

What I am struggling with is *which* half of the byte is linked to each of those two values. The reason for my confusion is conflicting information.
[This](http://vip.sugovica.hu/Sardi/kepnezo/JPEG%20File%20Layout%20and%20Format.htm) website states that the first four bits are the identification number, while the second four are precision.
[This](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/JPEG_-_Idea_and_Practice/The_header_part#The_Quantization_table_segment_DQT) website states the inverse.
[This](http://lad.dsc.ufcg.edu.br/multimidia/jpegmarker.pdf) document agrees with the latter.

**Which of these is correct?**

```
//i is the index of the 0xFF marker immediately before the 0xDB DQT marker byte
qTableID = (jpegData[i + 4] & 0xF0) >> 4; //gets the value of n: 0xn0
qTableID = (jpegData[i + 4] & 0x0F); //gets the value of n: 0x0n
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at the data of a few JPEG files I have determined that the first four bits are for precision and the second four are for the ID.